# use css for alignment and filling

Tags: javascript, css, positioning, alignment

I want to have a div that contains two other divs, a top div and a bottom div. The top div should be aligned to the top and have a auto-height, which depends on the content of the top div. The bottom div should fill out the empty area of the parent div.

I would like to make the alignment only with the use of CSS. I don't want to calc any positions or sizes by myself.

I tried the following:

1) http://jsfiddle.net/2dUxa/

Problem: If the parent is resized the bottom-div should move some pixels downwards.

2) http://jsfiddle.net/Th4Mn/

Problem: If the parent is resized the bottom-div should become smaller.

A solution with the use of javascript might look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2dUxa/7/
Is theire a solution without the use of javascript?

Comment: do you need the bottom div on your site? without that, it works.

Comment: yes I need it, because the bottom div is a scrollable area.

Comment: opacy: 1.0 does work with bottom div (second example)

Comment: I added the opacity of 0.5 only to show that it not works, the bottom div is too big.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about this: http://jsfiddle.net/2dUxa/3/

I change both div to `position: relative`, and give the bottom a `height: 100%`.

Then, set the #main `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: then I have the problem that I can't use the scrollbars of the bottom div

Answer (score 0):

Use this below markup and css..

This is with your code [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/9jTPF/) and below is my code

```
​<div id="main">

    <header>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mattis congue auctor. Proin iaculis blandit erat, nec vestibulum orci ultricies eget. Suspendisse viverra posuere urna, eu eleifend leo imperdiet at. Nulla lobortis, erat elementum placerat sagittis, est tellus hendrerit quam, quis iaculis leo est et mi.</p>
    </header>

    <footer>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mattis congue auctor. Proin iaculis blandit erat, nec vestibulum orci ultricies eget. Suspendisse viverra posuere urna, eu eleifend leo imperdiet at. Nulla lobortis, erat elementum placerat sagittis, est tellus hendrerit quam, quis iaculis leo est et mi.</p>
    </footer>

</div>
```

​

```
​#main{
width:80%;
height:300px;
position:relative;
background:#ddd;    
}
header{
width:100%;
height:auto;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
background:#aaa;    
}   
​footer{
width:100%;
height:auto;
position:absolute;    
bottom:0;
left:0;
background:#777;    
}
```

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A9Nbs/) running code... ​

Comment: It's not working. The 'top' position of the bottom div has always to have the same distance to to bottom-line of the top div.

Comment: What do you mean by same distance???
To move the footer as top float you must have to calculate either through jquery or need one more div in-between which will automatically move footer as header will float or changes height. [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/9jTPF/6/) if it works for you

Comment: I build a solution with the use of javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/2dUxa/7/ The bottom div is not a footer, but the top is like a header. The bottom div has to fill the empty area of the parent div. And I don't want to use javascript for this.

Comment: Okay so here what I understood that in total you have 3 divs' one is parent and two child divs in those one will be header or can say at the top (red) now and other will below red div which is bottom (green). You want the top div height flexible as per content and width and your bottom div (green) will start as soon as red div finish and that will filled up all area of parent div. if it is the case than please [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/9jTPF/12/) and [This Too](http://jsfiddle.net/9jTPF/13/) both are same but have different content if not than stil need to understand more.

Comment: the size of the parent div should stay fix, I want to use scrollbars in the bottom div

Comment: All at once: I have three div's. Two of them are the children of the remaining. child1 should have the following properties: left = 0, top = 0, right = 0, height = auto (regulated by its content). child2 should have the following properties: left = 0, right = 0, bottom = 0, top = child1.height. If the size (or position) of the parent div is modified all properties of child1 and child2 have to be preserved only with the use of CSS.